# "TypeError: Cannot find function map" when running JS using Java ScriptEngine

Tags: javascript, scriptengine

I'm trying to run some simple JavaScript function via ScriptEngine in Java, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function map. (<Unknown source>#8) in <Unknown source> at line number 8
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.invoke(RhinoScriptEngine.java:230)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.invokeFunction(RhinoScriptEngine.java:188)
at com.example.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:96)
```

My code:

test.js

```
function getRoots() {
    var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
    var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);

    println(roots);
}
```

TestClass main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        engine.eval(new FileReader("C:/path/to/my/js/file/test.js"));

        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;

        inv.invokeFunction("getRoots");
}
```

Error appears at line `var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);`

What I don't understand is: why is `map` function not found when running that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're using an old version of the Rhino engine that doesn't support `Array#map`. `Array#map` was added to JavaScript in version 1.6, and the latest version of Rhino *should* support JavaScript 1.7.

Whatever the reason your engine doesn't support `Array#map`, you should be able to use the polyfill in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to add support for it:

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.19
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19
if (!Array.prototype.map) {

  Array.prototype.map = function(callback/*, thisArg*/) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| 
    //    value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
    //    method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = arguments[1];
    }

    // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) 
    //    where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name and 
    //    len is the value of len.
    A = new Array(len);

    // 7. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 8. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
      //    method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
        //    method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal 
        //     method of callback with T as the this value and argument 
        //     list containing kValue, k, and O.
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
        // Pk, Property Descriptor
        // { Value: mappedValue,
        //   Writable: true,
        //   Enumerable: true,
        //   Configurable: true },
        // and false.

        // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
        // Object.defineProperty(A, k, {
        //   value: mappedValue,
        //   writable: true,
        //   enumerable: true,
        //   configurable: true
        // });

        // For best browser support, use the following:
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }

    // 9. return A
    return A;
  };
}
```